# iOS >> How do I recognize a gesture where the user leaves the UISlider Thumb property?

Tags: ios, uislider, gesture

In my app I use a UISlider created in the Storyboard and connected as an IBOutlet in the relevant UIViewController.

I have several actions occurring while the user is holding the UISlider and moving it around. I called them by creating an IBAction and connecting the Storyboard UISlider with "Value Change" Sent Event - this is the default "Sent Event" associated when connecting the UISlider with its .h file IBAction.

Now, there are several things I want to do when the user finally leaves the UISlider. Which Sent Event should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIControlEventTouchUpInside
```

is the one you want.